# DISK_FREE inconsistent with STATUS in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I use `show datanodes` command in cnosdb, find the inconsistence between `DISK_FREE` and `STATUS`.

To Reproduce:
Run run_cluster.sh to start the cluster and make the two data nodes in separated disks.

Make node 2001's disk full:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=5G bs=1G count=5`

Wait until status changed:
`public ❯ show datanodes;`
See the node 2001's `STATUS` is NODISKSPACE, `DISK_FREE` is 16.86Mb

Then free the disk:
`rm -rf 5G`

Wait a while then query again:
`public ❯ show datanodes;`

See the DISK_FREE has recovered to be 5G but the `STATUS` still been NODISKSPACE.

The `STATUS` should be HEALTHY when the space has freed.